# trying to find the text and change the anchor tag through html failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript inside a div, and trying to find it to replace a complete `a` tag with new type of `a` tag

Here is the html i have

```
<div class="info-more"><h3>We're here to help!</h3><p>Sales: 1-800-555-5555</p><p>Support:&nbsp;1-888-555-6655</p><a href="https://website.com" target="_blank">Click here to chat with us</a></div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($(document).find(".info-more").text());
    $(".info-more").closest("a").attr("href","javascript:;");
});
```

Comment: Use `.find()` instead of `.closest()`. `.find()` will look for a child element... While `.closest()` looks for a parent element. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use .`find()` instead of `.closest()`. [Find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will look at descendants (ie children of the selector element), whereas, [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will look only at the parents of the selector element as it traverses up through its ancestors to find the selector.

See working example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($(".info-more").find("a").text());
  $(".info-more").find("a").attr("href", "javascript:;");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info-more">
  <h3>We're here to help!</h3>
  <p>Sales: 1-800-555-5555</p>
  <p>Support:&nbsp;1-888-555-6655</p>
  <a href="https://website.com" target="_blank">Click here to chat with us</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried your code and the console.is showing just empty i tried with text or html both `$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log($(document).find(".info-more").find("a").text());
 $(".info-more").find("a").attr("href", "javascript:;");
});`

Comment: When I run the code you've given me, it outputs "Click here to chat with us" in the console. Is this what you want? It also changes the a `href` link. Run my code snippet above. It should produce the same output.